# Android Seekbar multiple ticks

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Is it possible to have multiple tick marks styles in a single seekbar? I want to create something like the image below but can't find anyway to do so using custom tick marks. Only way I know of would be to create a custom background drawable for the seekbar and set the seekbars background to that hoping that the image ticks match up with my progress amounts.

[image]

Here is my current code to create a seekbar with default ticks.

seekbar_thumb

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/thumb" />
        <size
            android:width="50dp"
            android:height="50dp" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/wb_white" android:width="1dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
            android:width="35dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#4BA9D6"/>
        <size
            android:width="1dp"
            android:height="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

seekbar xml

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:progress="1"
    android:max="10" />
```

Seekbar progress changed code

```
slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
    if(progressValue == 10){
        slider.setProgress(progressValue - 1);
        return;
    }

    if(progressValue % 2 == 0){
        slider.setProgress(progressValue + 1);
        return;
    }
}
```